# Call external dojo javascript in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I hava a external javascript file "RestAPI.js"  which look like :

```
function RestAPI(){ self = this; }
RestAPI.prototype = {
self: null,
urlString: "http://175.xxx.xxx.xxx/JSON/Handler1.ashx",
UserAuthentication:function(userName,passsword,successFunction,failFunction,token) {
    var data = { 'interface': 'RestAPI', 'method': 'UserAuthentication', 'parameters': {'userName':userName,'passsword':passsword}, 'token': token };

    var jsonData = dojo.toJson(data);
    var xhrArgs = {
        url: self.urlString,
        handleAs: 'json',
        postData: jsonData,
        load: successFunction,
        error: failFunction };
    var deferred = dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
}
};
```

I would like to call "UserAuthentication" function in my HTML page.

```
<script src="RestAPI.js">
function SendToServer()
{
    var username = "abc";
    var password = "123";
    var a = RestAPI();
    a.UserAuthentication(username,password);
}
</script>
```

But it does not work out for me, anything that I missing out ? I have google around for few week , didn't manage to get any solution. Appreciated if any help can guide me through this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things going on here:

Firstly you are putting the "Send to Server" function in a script block which sources the external javascript file.  Most browsers will not parse the internals of the block if there is an external file to source.

Secondly as you have defined `RestAPI` as an object with a constructor,  and instance context you need to call it like one to use it how you intend;  use the `new` keyword to create a new instance of the RestAPI Object.

```
<script src="RestAPI.js"></script>
<script>
    function SendToServer() {
        var username = "abc"
          , password = "123"
          , a        = new RestAPI()
          ;
        a.UserAuthentication(username, password);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: There is a error
    XMLHttpRequest cannot load     http://175.xxx.xxx.xxx/JSON/Handler1.ashx. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: That is a separate issue related to loading files from different domains or from your local file system; if you are working locally you either need to set up a webserver on localhost or launch your browser with cross origin security disabled

Comment: Appreciated for your help. Can you explain more about this kind of error ?
Because later on I will using it for phonegap , wondering this kind of error will occur at the phone or not.

Comment: You need to ask a new question about PhoneGap (I do not use the system)